# Android - How to create small notification of 'New Posts' like in twitter mobile app

Tags: java, android, twitter, feed

Twitter mobile app shows 'New Posts' notification as shown in following figure

[image: Twitter mobile app snap]

If we click on this notification, it scroll up to the latest post. How to create this kind of notification?

Comment: this is just a button on top of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking, this is a new tool like snackBar and Toast.